# Spring-Camel-Kafka : 1 Consumer and multiple Topics not working using 'camel-kafka' component

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-kafka

Please find below the code snippet:

properties file:

```
consumer.topic=FIRST,SECOND 
consumer.group=group1
```

Route.java:

```
from("kafka:{{kafka.url}}?topic={{consumer.topic}}&groupId={{consumer.group}}&autoOffsetReset=earliest&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}")
```

The topics **FIRST** and **SECOND** are being considered as a single topic instead of being considered as two different ones. Can someone please help me by explaining how should they be configured in the properties file to be resolved as two?

LOG:

```
KafkaTopic[FIRST,SECOND]] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2159 : {FIRST,SECOND=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried using a newer release

Comment: Camel Version : 2.17.0
JDK : 1.8

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported in Camel 2.17.0.

The multiple topics subscription has been introduced from Camel 2.17.1 onwards and Camel 2.18.x onwards.

Here is the commit related to this change on 2.17.x branch:
https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/a8f32d4ec485419cd196988f0de938d6f9b3cc49

and here is the commit related to this change on 2.18.x branch:
https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/d7fc67fa16d083e570650aa20c064d609b469641

You have to upgrade to Camel >=2.17.1 or 2.18.x

For completeness here is the issue on Camel JIRA
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9835

Comment: :Thank you so much, i upgraded the version to 2.17.1 and it worked. I was concentrating more on 2.17 and ignored its child version. :)